# I want to check is students are failing in a course, if none are, print “no students failing”

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I have a list with students in a course and their grades. I want to check if there are any failing the course (their average being less than 60%).

I want to run a for loop, and if the condition isn’t met by the end of the loop (student’s average is less than 60%), print “No failing students”.
However, I want to print all the students that are failing, if there are some. So I need to continue the loop without it breaking when it sees the first failing student.

This is my code. I read online to use the break function with else outside the loop, but like that, the loop stops when it sees the first failing student.

```
slist = [[“Andrew”, 29, 67, 58], [“Charles”, 98, 76, 85], [“Penny”, 63, 45, 23]]
for students in slist:
  total = 0
  count = 0
  for grade in students[1:len(students)]:
    grade = int(grade)
    total += grade
    count += 1
  average = total/count
  student = students[0]
  if average < 60:
      print(f"{student} is failing with {average}%!")
      break
else:
  print(“No failing students!”)
```

The output ends up being:

```
output:
Andrew is failing with 51.333%!
```

Also, whenever I remove the break statement, it prints all the failing students, and that there are no failing students:

```
output:
Andrew is failing with 51.333%!
Penny is failing with 43.666%!
No failing students!
```

I want the output to be:

```
output:
Andrew is failing with 51.333%!
Penny is failing with 43.666%!
```

And when the condition isn’t met and no students are failing:

```
output:
No failing students!
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your `break` statement? How will the code change if you were to remove it?

Comment: @TomerAriel when the break statement isn’t there, it prints all the failed students as well as that there are no failing students. So it says Andrew and Penny are failing and that there are no failing students.

Comment: Alright, then it is an easy problem to fix. There are several ways to handle this case. For example - are you familiar with the concept of a `boolean flag`? Can you imagine how a variable such as `any_failing_students` or `no_failing_students` might be useful?

Comment: The break statement stops the loop prematurely so you shouldn't use a for/else loop in this case since you want the loop to complete. you can use a flag instead (a boolean variable that changes to True if someone fails and triggers the print)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping with what you want your output to be, and with low modification of your code:

```py
slist = [['Andrew', 29, 67, 58], ['Charles', 98, 76, 85], ['Penny', 63, 45, 23]]
flist = []
for students in slist:
  total = 0
  count = 0
  for grade in students[1:len(students)]:
    grade = int(grade)
    total += grade
    count += 1
  average = total/count
  student = students[0]
  if average < 60:
      print(f"{student} is failing with {average}%!")
      flist.append(students)
if flist == []:
  print('No failing students!')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the question posed by the OP, two problems stood out: the use of 'smart quotes', as used in word processors, instead of 'straight quotes' as used in code editors. This makes me wonder, whether the code was copied and pasted from a word processor. The other issue might have flowed directly from this: the else statement on line 14 is not matched by an if statement. At first sight, this may not be obvious and seem to match the if statement on line 11, but in a code editor it stands out like the proverbial 'sore thumb' that it doesn't. In Python, indents matter. Having recognised this, it's not difficult to figure out why the OP's code doesn't  work, and it's easy to fix:

```
slist = [["Andrew", 29, 67, 58], ["Charles", 98, 76, 85], ["Penny", 63, 45, 23]]
nofail = True
for students in slist:
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for grade in students[1:len(students)]:
        grade = int(grade)
        total += grade
        count += 1
    average = total/count
    student = students[0]
    if average < 60:
        print(f"{student} is failing with {average}%!")
        nofail = False
if nofail:
    print("No failing students!")
```

I should, however, recommend to use the following:

```
score = int(grade)
total += score
```

because grade is effectively used as an index into the students list, and therefore: grade = int(grade), although it works in code, might be confusing to the reader. Another improvement might be to format the printed values.

The previous answers seem to have been a case of students (like myself) helping other students, and in this respect I frankly have an issue with some answers having been marked down, without bothering to provide any comments as to why. All the answers work, and whether they are 'elegant' or not should not be an issue here. I hope that moderators will look into this kind of practice. Sure, the answer provided by @Viktor Mellgren didn't work for me 'out of the box', but I suspect that this is due to him using an older version of Python. To make his answer work in Python 3.11, I had to amend it as follows:

```
allScores=[*map(score, slist)]
onlyScoring=[*filter(lambda x: (x != ""), allScores)]
if not onlyScoring:
  print("No failing students!")
else:
  for z in onlyScoring:
    print(z)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sList = [["Andrew", 29, 67, 58], ["Charles", 98, 76, 85], ["Penny", 63, 45, 23]]
fail = []

for name, *grades in sList:
    grade = sum(grades) / 3

    if grade < 60:
        fail.append([name, grade])
        print(f"{name} is failing with {grade:.2f}%!")



if len(fail) == 0:
    print('no student is failing')
else:
   print(fail)
```

which will output:

```
Andrew is failing with 51.34%!
Penny is failing with 43.67%!
[['Andrew', 51.333333333333334], ['Penny', 43.666666666666664]]
```

and will output:

```
no student is failing
```

if no students are failing.

Hopefully this helps and is what you're wanting!

Answer (score -1):

A more functional approach

```py
def score(students):
  total = 0
  count = 0
  for grade in students[1:len(students)]:
    grade = int(grade)
    total += grade
    count += 1
  average = total/count
  student = students[0]
  if average < 60:
      return(f"{student} is failing with {average}%!")
  return ""

slist = [["Andrew", 99, 67, 58], ["Charles", 98, 76, 85], ["Penny", 63, 45, 99]]

allScores=map(score, slist)
onlyScoring=filter(lambda x: (x != ""), allScores)
if not onlyScoring == []:
  print("No failing students!")
else:
  for z in onlyScoring:
    print(z)
```

Comment: Something smells fishy... the code-highlight isn't right

Comment: @UndoneStudios fixed, something wonky with the " character when i copy pasted from editor